# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier / Typescript class

Tags: typescript, poo

Estoy intentado crear una clase en mi archivo.ts pero me devuelve este error en la linea donde agrego la propiedad code: String; no veo donde esta mi error.

```
class Rocket {
    code:string; // En esta linea marca el error
    numThrusters:number;

    constructor(code: string, numThrusters: number) {
        this.code = code;
        this.numThrusters = numThrusters;
    }
}

var rocket1 = new Rocket('32WESSDS', 3);
var rocket2 = new Rocket('LDSFJA32', 6);

console.log(rocket1);
console.log(rocket2);
```

Comment: Ya lo veo... Imagino que tengo algun problema con mis archivos, a ver que puedo averiguar

Answer (score 1):

Me ocurrió lo mismo, como lo resolví...

Estaba mirando la etiqueta script del html donde usaba el JS y claro, no estaba utilizando el JS, estaba usando el TS...

Así que cambié la extensión del archivo TS a JS y listo.

Antes:

```
<script src="config/config.ts"></script>
```

Ahora:

```
<script src="config/config.js"></script>
```